# Run virtual machine at startup

Tags: virtualbox, boot

I have a Windows server that runs in a virtual machine on Linux Mint.
I have a command in the "start up apps" to start it when I log in, but I'd like it to start when Linux starts, before anyone logs in.

How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can place the command to start the virtual machine in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit` line. This will run the command after booting the machine without need of a user to log in.

Comment: Well, this doesn't work, for some reason. I can run `service rc.local start` and it will run as expected... but it doesn't work on startup. I can confirm that rc.local is running at startup, just not my VBoxManage command.

Comment: Probably you only need to add a small delay to the script to let everything running before starting the VM. I think 30 sec to 1 min should be sufficient (`sleep 60` for example)